# Kohana database error: newly-created table doesn't exist

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-db

The table `kohana_blog. article` is created. But it still prompts this error. Not sure what is the problem. This is the error seen:

```
Database_Exception [ 1146 ]: Table 'kohana_blog. article' doesn't exist [ SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM ` article` ]
```

Comment: Is there a blank space in name ` article`? Show us your table definition and your query if you want to get helped!

Comment: i am newbie to kohana framework. I just discover that kohana framework auto add single code to my table name. The table name should be article instead of 'article' .  Thanks Marco

Comment: @gladys - Welcome to StackOverflow! I did a bit of cleanup on your question. In future questions, you should strive for more descriptive question titles. Information like error codes should be included in the body, not the title.

Answer (score 0):

> Table '**kohana_blog. article**' doesn't exist [ SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM **`article`** ]

There is a blank space in table name

check your config and remove the blank space should resolve this problem